# Error listing result for googlesearch-python 1.1.0

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, google-search

When I try to print the results of the googlesearch-python 1.1.0 "search" query, either by using the list() constructor or by iterating through the results, i get the error 'URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>'.

The error only occurs if I use the "num_results" parameter, for example:

```
num_results = 3
for urls in search("Google", num_results):
    print(urls)
```

If don't use the "num_results" parameter, the search works normally, but it is delayed and run the risk of get blocked by google for making new requests.

I came up with a quick solution to still be able to use the library and limit the searches:

```
for i,urls in enumerate(search("Google",limit)):
    print(urls)
    if i == 1: break
```

But I'd like to get the solution to the original bug:

I attach the whole error, which apparently involves the requests library:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\urllib\request.py:1346, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1345 try:
-> 1346     h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1347               encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1348 except OSError as err: # timeout error

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\http\client.py:1285, in HTTPConnection.request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1284 """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1285 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\http\client.py:1331, in HTTPConnection._send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1330     body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1331 self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\http\client.py:1280, in HTTPConnection.endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1279     raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1280 self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\http\client.py:1040, in HTTPConnection._send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1039 del self._buffer[:]
-> 1040 self.send(msg)
   1042 if message_body is not None:
   1043 
   1044     # create a consistent interface to message_body

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\http\client.py:980, in HTTPConnection.send(self, data)
    979 if self.auto_open:
--> 980     self.connect()
    981 else:

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\http\client.py:1447, in HTTPSConnection.connect(self)
   1445 "Connect to a host on a given (SSL) port."
-> 1447 super().connect()
   1449 if self._tunnel_host:

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\http\client.py:946, in HTTPConnection.connect(self)
    945 """Connect to the host and port specified in __init__."""
--> 946 self.sock = self._create_connection(
    947     (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
    948 # Might fail in OSs that don't implement TCP_NODELAY

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\socket.py:823, in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    822 err = None
--> 823 for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
    824     af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\socket.py:954, in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    953 addrlist = []
--> 954 for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    955     af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [14], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 from googlesearch import search
      2 limit=2
----> 3 for i,urls in enumerate(search("Google",limit)):
      4     print(urls)
      5     if i == 1: break

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\site-packages\googlesearch\__init__.py:272, in search(query, tld, lang, tbs, safe, num, start, stop, pause, country, extra_params, user_agent, verify_ssl)
    265         raise ValueError(
    266             'GET parameter "%s" is overlapping with \
    267             the built-in GET parameter',
    268             builtin_param
    269         )
    271 # Grab the cookie from the home page.
--> 272 get_page(url_home % vars(), user_agent, verify_ssl)
    274 # Prepare the URL of the first request.
    275 if start:

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\site-packages\googlesearch\__init__.py:174, in get_page(url, user_agent, verify_ssl)
    172 cookie_jar.add_cookie_header(request)
    173 if verify_ssl:
--> 174     response = urlopen(request)
    175 else:
    176     context = ssl._create_unverified_context()

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\urllib\request.py:214, in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    212 else:
    213     opener = _opener
--> 214 return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\urllib\request.py:517, in OpenerDirector.open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    514     req = meth(req)
    516 sys.audit('urllib.Request', req.full_url, req.data, req.headers, req.get_method())
--> 517 response = self._open(req, data)
    519 # post-process response
    520 meth_name = protocol+"_response"

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\urllib\request.py:534, in OpenerDirector._open(self, req, data)
    531     return result
    533 protocol = req.type
--> 534 result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
    535                           '_open', req)
    536 if result:
    537     return result

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\urllib\request.py:494, in OpenerDirector._call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    492 for handler in handlers:
    493     func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 494     result = func(*args)
    495     if result is not None:
    496         return result

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\urllib\request.py:1389, in HTTPSHandler.https_open(self, req)
   1388 def https_open(self, req):
-> 1389     return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
   1390         context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)

File ~\Anaconda3\envs\DRI\lib\urllib\request.py:1349, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1346         h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
   1347                   encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1348     except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1349         raise URLError(err)
   1350     r = h.getresponse()
   1351 except:

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

I have tried reinstalling another version of the library requests as i got the following message when I installed the google-search library:

ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behavior is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
googlesearch-python 1.1.0 requires requests==2.25.1, but you have requests 2.28.2 which is incompatible.

despite using the command pip install --force-reinstall -v "requests>=2.25.1" the incompatibility message remains.

Comment: what makes you think this has something to do with the requests library?

Comment: Because of the conflict warning for the requirement of version 2.25.1 of the 'requests' library for 'googlesearch-python 1.1.0.'